# material design lite table select

Tags: material-design-lite

I am just wondering how I could take advantage of the data-* attribute when using the mdl table.
data-mdl-data-table-selectable-name="materials[]" data-mdl-data-table-selectable-value="acrylic"

how could I listen for the select event and retrieve the selected rows?

Comment: MDL `data-table`  has no default function to gather selected value into `data-mdl-data-table-selectable-value` or `data-mdl-data-table-selectable-name`? Are you asking about how to implement one?